# Does restriction of a topology-determining cover determine subspace topology?

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X, \mathcal{T})$ be a topological space, and $\mathcal{C} \subset \mathcal{P}(X)$ be a cover of $X$ which [determines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_topology) $\mathcal{T}$. That is, $U \cap C \in \mathcal{T}|C$ for each $C \in \mathcal{C}$ implies $U \in \mathcal{T}$, where $\mathcal{T}|C = \{U \cap C : U \in \mathcal{T}\}$. Let $X' \subset X$.

Does $\mathcal{C}|X'$ determine $\mathcal{T}|X'$?

I can prove that this holds when $X'$ is locally closed, i.e. $X' = A \cap B$ for some $A \in \mathcal{T}$ and $B \in \mathcal{T}^C $, where $\mathcal{T}^C$ denotes closed subsets. I suspect the result does not hold for general subsets, but what might be a counter-example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X = \{0, 1, 2\}$, $\mathcal{T} = \{\emptyset, X\}$, $\mathcal{C} = \{\{0, 1\}, \{0, 2\}\}$. Then $\mathcal{C}$ determines $\mathcal{T}$. Let $X' = \{1, 2\}$. Then $\mathcal{T}|X' = \{\emptyset, X'\}$, and $\mathcal{C}|X' = \{\{1\}, \{2\}\}$. The latter determines the discrete topology on $X'$, which does not equal the trivial subspace topology.

The answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4697519/51161) characterizes in terms of closure when a cover determines topology hereditarily.