# Closure by cover

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X, \mathcal{T})$ be a topological space, $\mathcal{C} \subset \mathcal{P}(X)$ be a cover of $X$, $\mathcal{C}$ determine $\mathcal{T}$, and $A \subset X$.

#### Problem

Does it hold that

$$\overline{A}(X) = \bigcup \{\overline{A \cap C}(C) : C \in \mathcal{C}\}.$$

?

#### Background

#### Notation

- $\mathcal{C}$ determines $\mathcal{T}$ if $U \cap C \in \mathcal{T}|C$ for each $C \in \mathcal{C}$ implies $U \in \mathcal{T}$.
- $\mathcal{T}|C$ denotes the subspace topology on $C$.
- $\overline{A \cap C}(C)$ is the closure of $A \cap C$ on $C$.
- $\mathcal{T}^C$ denotes closed sets.

#### Theorem 1

Even without assuming that $\mathcal{C}$ determines $\mathcal{T}$,

$$\overline{A}(X) = \overline{\bigcup \{\overline{A \cap C}(C) : C \in \mathcal{C}\}}(X).$$

#### Proof (sketch)

Use the facts that $\overline{A \cap C}(C) \subset \overline{A}(X) \cap C$, and that closure is increasing and idempotent.

#### Theorem 2

The result holds when $\mathcal{C} \subset \mathcal{T}$.

#### Proof

We have $\overline{A \cap C}(C) \cap D = \overline{A}(X) \cap C \cap D \subset \overline{A}(X) \cap D = \overline{A \cap D}(D)$ for each $C, D \in \mathcal{C}$. Hence

$$\bigcup \{\overline{A \cap C}(C) : C \in \mathcal{C}\} \cap D = \overline{A \cap D}(D) \in \mathcal{T}^C|D.$$

Since $\mathcal{C}$ determines $\mathcal{T}$,

$$\bigcup \{\overline{A \cap C}(C) : C \in \mathcal{C}\} \in \mathcal{T}^C.$$

Hence the closure in Theorem 1 can be removed. Note that an open cover determines topology, so it is not needed to assume it here.

#### Theorem 3

The result holds when $\mathcal{C} \subset \mathcal{T}^C$ and $\mathcal{C}$ is locally finite.

#### Proof

Then $\overline{A \cap C}(C) \in \mathcal{T}^C$, and a union of a locally finite collection of closed subsets is closed. Hence the closure in Theorem 1 can be removed. Note that a locally finite closed cover determines topology, so it is not needed to assume it here.

#### Theorem 4

The result holds when $\mathcal{C}$ determines $\mathcal{T}$,  $\mathcal{C} \subset \mathcal{T}^C$ and $\mathcal{C}|D$ is $\mathcal{T}|D$-locally finite for each $D \in \mathcal{C}$.

#### Proof

This is similar to theorem 3. We have

$$\bigcup \{\overline{A \cap C}(C) : C \in \mathcal{C}\} \cap D \in \mathcal{T}^C|D.$$

Then since $\mathcal{C}$ determines $\mathcal{T}$, the result follows.

#### Theorem 5

Suppose $\mathcal{C}$ is a cover of $X$, and

$$\overline{A}(X) = \bigcup \{\overline{A \cap C}(C) : C \in \mathcal{C}\}$$

for each $A \subset X$. Then $\mathcal{C}$ determines $\mathcal{T}$.

#### Proof

Suppose $A \cap C \in \mathcal{T}^C|C$ for each $C \in \mathcal{C}$. Then

$$\overline{A}(X) = \bigcup \{\overline{A \cap C}(C) : C \in \mathcal{C}\} = \bigcup \{A \cap C : C \in \mathcal{C}\} = A.$$

Therefore $A \in \mathcal{T}^C$; i.e. $\mathcal{C}$ determines $\mathcal{T}$.

#### Conjecture

The thing that is common for open covers and locally finite closed covers is that they determine the topology. Hence the question. Theorem 4 also suggests another condition, that $\mathcal{C}$ determines $\mathcal{T}$, and $\mathcal{C}|D$ determines $\mathcal{T}|D$ for each  $D \in \mathcal{C}$. However, since $D \in \mathcal{C}$, $\mathcal{C}|D$ *always* determines $\mathcal{T}|D$, so that condition does not add anything.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @StevenClontz The question is whether the claim in the problem section holds.

Comment: What does "$\mathcal{C}$ determines $\mathcal{T}$" mean?

Comment: @PaulFrost It is defined in the background section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the claim does not hold. I'll give a counter-example below. But first a characterization:

#### Theorem 6 (Characterization by closure)

The following are equivalent:

- $\overline{A}(X) = \bigcup \{\overline{A \cap C}(C) : C \in \mathcal{C}\}$ for each $A \subset X$.
- $\mathcal{C}|X'$ determines $\mathcal{T}|X'$ for each $X' \subset X$.

#### Proof

$\implies$

Suppose

$$\overline{A}(X) = \bigcup \{\overline{A \cap C}(C) : C \in \mathcal{C}\}$$

holds for each $A \subset X$. Let $X' \subset X$. Then

$$
\begin{aligned}
\overline{A \cap X'}(X') & = \overline{A \cap X'}(X) \cap X' \\
{} & = \bigcup \{\overline{A \cap C \cap X'}(C) \cap X' : C \in \mathcal{C}\} \\
{} & = \bigcup \{\overline{A \cap C \cap X'}(C \cap X') : C \in \mathcal{C}\} \\
{} & = \bigcup \{\overline{A \cap X' \cap C'}(C') : C' \in \mathcal{C}|X'\}.
\end{aligned}
$$

Therefore, by Theorem 5 in the question, $\mathcal{C}|X'$ determines $\mathcal{T}|X'$ for each $X' \subset X$.

$\impliedby$

By contraposition. Suppose there exists $A \subset X$ such that

$$\overline{A}(X) \neq \bigcup \{\overline{A \cap C}(C) : C \in \mathcal{C}\}$$

Let

$$
\begin{aligned}
L & = \overline{A}(X), \\
R & = \bigcup \{\overline{A \cap C}(C) : C \in \mathcal{C}\}, \\
p & \in L \setminus R, \\
X' & = A \cup \{p\}.
\end{aligned}
$$

We claim that $\mathcal{C}|X'$ does not determine $\mathcal{T}|X'$. Note that $p \not\in A$, since $A \subset R$. Let $C \in \mathcal{C}$, and $C' = C \cap X'$. Then

$$
\begin{aligned}
\overline{A \cap C'}(C') & = \overline{A \cap (C \cap X')}(C \cap X') \\
{} & = \overline{A \cap C}(C) \cap (C \cap X') \\
{} & = \overline{A \cap C}(C) \cap C \cap (A \cup \{p\}) \\
{} & = \overline{A \cap C}(C) \cap ((A \cap C) \cup (\{p\} \cap C)) \\
{} & = (A \cap C) \cup (\overline{A \cap C}(C) \cap \{p\} \cap C)) \\
{} & = A \cap C \\
{} & = (A \cap X') \cap C \\
{} & = A \cap C'.
\end{aligned}
$$

Therefore $A \cap C' \in \mathcal{T}^C|C'$. On the other hand,

$$
\begin{aligned}
\overline{A}(X') & = \overline{A}(X) \cap X' \\
{} & = \overline{A}(X) \cap (A \cup \{p\}) \\
{} & = A \cup \{p\} \\
{} & \neq A.
\end{aligned}
$$

Therefore $A \not\in \mathcal{T}^C|X'$; i.e. $\mathcal{C}|X'$ does not determine $\mathcal{T}|X'$.

QED

#### Counter-example

Open covers and locally finite closed covers are hereditarily topology-determining. However, it [does not hold](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4680492/51161) for a general topology-determining cover. We use the counter-example in that link to provide a counter-example to our question. Let

$$
\begin{aligned}
X & = \{0, 1, 2\}, \\
\mathcal{T} & = \{\emptyset, X\}, \\
\mathcal{C} & = \{\{0, 1\}, \{0, 2\}\}, \\
A & = \{1\}.
\end{aligned}
$$

Then $\mathcal{C}$ determines $\mathcal{T}$, and $\overline{A}(X) = \{0, 1, 2\}$. In fact, $\mathcal{C}|X'$ determines $\mathcal{T}|X'$ for each $X' \subset X$ except $X' = \{1, 2\}$. We then have that

$$\bigcup \{\overline{A \cap C}(C) : C \in \mathcal{C}\} = \{0, 1\}.$$

#### Theorem 7 (Bonus: Characterization by boundary)

The following are equivalent:

- $\partial A (X) = \bigcup \{\partial(A \cap C)(C) : C \in \mathcal{C}\}$ for each $A \subset X$.
- $\mathcal{C}|X'$ determines $\mathcal{T}|X'$ for each $X' \subset X$.

#### Proof

$\implies$

Suppose

$$\partial A (X) = \bigcup \{\partial(A \cap C)(C) : C \in \mathcal{C}\}.$$

Adding $A$ to both sides (by union) provides

$$\overline{A}(X) = \bigcup \{\overline{A \cap C}(C) : C \in \mathcal{C}\}.$$

By Theorem 6, $\mathcal{C}|X'$ determines $\mathcal{T}|X'$ for each $X' \subset X$.

$\impliedby$

By contraposition. Suppose there exists $A \subset X$ such that

$$\partial A (X) \neq \bigcup \{\partial(A \cap C)(C) : C \in \mathcal{C}\}.$$

Let
$$
\begin{aligned}
L & = \partial A (X), \\
R & = \bigcup \{\partial(A \cap C)(C) : C \in \mathcal{C}\}, \\
p & \in L \setminus R.
\end{aligned}
$$

If $p \not\in A$, adding $A$ to both $L$ and $R$ shows that

$$\overline{A}(X) \neq \bigcup \{\overline{A \cap C}(C) : C \in \mathcal{C}\}.$$

If $p \in A$, then $p \not\in X \setminus A$, and we can rewrite our terms as

$$
\begin{aligned}
L & = \partial (X \setminus A) (X) \\
R & = \bigcup \{\partial((X \setminus A) \cap C)(C) : C \in \mathcal{C}\}.
\end{aligned}
$$

Adding $X \setminus A$ to both $L$ and $R$ shows that

$$\overline{X \setminus A}(X) \neq \bigcup \{\overline{(X \setminus A) \cap C}(C) : C \in \mathcal{C}\}.$$

In either case, by Theorem 6, $\mathcal{C}|X'$ does not determine $\mathcal{T}|X'$ for some $X' \subset X$.