# If hypercomponents determine topology, do they determine topology hereditarily?

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X, \mathcal{T})$ be a topological space, and $\mathcal{C} \subset \mathcal{P}(X)$ be the set of [hyperconnected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperconnected_space) components of $X$. Suppose $\mathcal{C}$ determines $\mathcal{T}$.

Does $\mathcal{C}$ determine $\mathcal{T}$ hereditarily?

#### Background

- $\mathcal{C}$ [determines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_topology) $\mathcal{T}$ if $U \cap C \in \mathcal{T}|C$ for each $C \in \mathcal{C}$ implies $U \in \mathcal{T}$ (for each $U \subset X$).
- $\mathcal{C}$ determines $\mathcal{T}$ hereditarily, if $\mathcal{C}|X'$ determines $\mathcal{T}|X'$ for each $X' \subset X$, where $\mathcal{C}|X' = \{C \cap X' : C \in \mathcal{C}\}$.
- Hereditarily topology-determining covers include open covers and locally finite closed covers.
- A characterization of hereditarily topology-determining covers in terms of closure is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4697519/closure-by-cover).
- A cover which determines topology [may not determine topology hereditarily](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4680492/51161).
- The corresponding claim is true when hyperconnectedness is replaced with [connectedness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space), [pathconnectedness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#Path_connectedness), or [ultraconnectedness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraconnected_space). This is because under the assumption of topology-determination they all form open covers.
- Hypercomponents are closed, and generally not open.
- The claim holds when hypercomponents are locally finite, because then they form a locally finite closed cover.
- In general, hypercomponents [may not be locally finite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4611804/hyperconnected-components-may-not-be-disjoint).
- The claim holds when $\mathcal{C}|D$ is $(\mathcal{T}|D)$-locally finite for each $D \in \mathcal{C}$, see Theorem 4 [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4697519/closure-by-cover). This is why the claim also holds for the excluded point topology in the previous link.